# What are the differences between the difficulties?

Tags: mighty-no-9

There are 4 difficulties: Normal, Hard, Hyper, and Maniac. The "Tips" menu gives little information about what's different between difficulties, and the only relevant results I've found on Google are videos of people beating various levels at these higher difficulties.

What exactly are the differences between the difficulty levels in Mighty No. 9?

Answer (score 1):

on hard and hyper the enemy damage and their behavior becomes more aggressive and they move considerably faster. Items for healing and extra lives also do not show up. In maniac mode the difficulty is in the 1 hit deaths. Any damage will kill you, but the enemy speed and behavior  is the same as in normal mode as well as items still show up.